# Determining the correct .net project code used to create the production application.

Tags: .net

This may sound crazy but I have many copies of a .net project's source code in source control but am trying to figure out which copy of the source code in the version control system is the correct code that was used to build the currently deployed production application's projects. The application was deployed several years ago and we have several versions of the source code but don't know which version in source control matches the actual production's code. I have read about a tool called Refelector but was wondering if there was a more simple way to go. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really isn't an easy way to determine what code was used for a years-old application unless you do want to reverse engineer it and compare it over time. If you know the exact build date, you can probably just go to that point in time in the history and see if there's mention of a release build, version commit, or something. That's assuming that useful comments were added to each commit.

Revision control systems usually support tagging for releases or whatever else you may want to "checkpoint" it for. With each formal build (beta, release candidate, production), the last revision number contained in the build should be tagged. This makes it easy to jump to the source used for a particular build.

Comment: What I was thinking was if I were to pull the dll's off of the production machine and load each project one at a time in to VS, build the project source code in release mode then compare the dll sizes. Then the dll build the matches the production dll size would be the correct one. Does this make since?

Comment: That might work, but sizes can change even if code didn't. It depends on compiler optimization, the system, etc. Unless you replicate the exact conditions of the initial build, you might not be able to use that method. But, if you have the time, it's worth a shot.